# Windows symlink multiple images to new folder, can't iterate through symlinks using Photos app, and Explorer does not display image thumbnails

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, photos, python3

I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/creating-hard-and-soft-links-using-powershell) how to make symlinks in Windows. I think Python actually uses the Powershell command `New-Item` under the hood to make symlinks in Windows. I make a bunch of symlinks that point to a bunch of images, using the `pathlib.Path` method `symlink_to()` in Python 3.6. The method succeeds, and now I have a bunch of image symlinks in a new folder. HOWEVER, the Windows Photos app cannot iterate through the symlinks as images in the same way it could with the real image files. The symlinks open correctly under the Photos app, but once open, I can't press up or down or right or left to iterate through the files in the folder. Is this a bug? How can I get around this?

Just to clarify, the symlinks have the same file names, including the extension. Also, Windows file explorer does not display the image thumbnails.

Comment: Have the links got the same extension (eg `.JPG`) as the files they are pointing to? If not, an application looking for other image files probably won't find them.

Comment: The symlinks have precisely the same file names, including the extension.